# How to use less in react

Tags: craco, react-18

I want to use less in react18, before that I installed and configured "**@craco/craco**", but when executing "**npm i craco-less -D**", the console prompts an error, I searched a lot without finding it, looking forward to your reply!

> Console error reporting：
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xKIV.png)
> package.json
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IWCT.png)
> craco.config.js
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIbPq.png)

Comment: Try it `--force` flag.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. Just upvote my answer and accept it (click the grey checkmark).

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code or error messages. They present accessibility barriers and can't be searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install it using the `--force` flag, like:

```
npm install craco-less --save-dev --force
```

Or for short:

```
npm i craco-less -D -f
```

Comment: Just explain the downvote, the OP had some conflicts and that could be solved with `--force` flag so what's wrong about that?